# Problem with htaccess redirect wrong url to error file

Tags: php, html, .htaccess

In my htaccess file I changed the names from my pages so that the urls look more clean.
But I also added the following code to make sure that if someone enters a wrong url that the error page is shown.

```
RewriteRule ^error$ pages/error.php [L]
ErrorDocument 403 pages/error.php
ErrorDocument 404 pages/error.php
ErrorDocument 500 pages/error.php
```

Why, when I enter a wrong url it just shows pages/error.php in stead of redirecting to error page?

I also tried putting the name 'error' in stead of the whole url cause earlier in the document i change its name to error but that still doesn't work.

Comment: This is not a redirect, but only an internal rewrite. (And it rewrites only for that one specific URL, `error`, and nothing else.) You should not _redirect_ to error pages in the first place, that is counter productive - clients will not get the appropriate status code for the _originally_ requested URL any more, if you do that.